# Windows debugger output - problems with executing some execs

Tags: windbg

on Win7 I have a problem with sudden termination of some apps. It includes e.g. Office365 installation file. After executing of such file it just finishes with statement that this program has stopped working. So I tried to debug it and this is the output of windows debugger:

```
CommandLine: D:\Instalki\Setup.X86.pl-pl_O365ProPlusRetail_87b3383c-4012-4e3b-b79a-506c29e30448_TX_PR_.exe

************* Symbol Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                         
SRV*f:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: SRV*f:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00190000 00282000   bootstrapper.exe
ModLoad: 76ff0000 7712c000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 76080000 76154000   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
ModLoad: 74620000 7466b000   C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 751d0000 75270000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 746c0000 7476c000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 76580000 76599000   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 74770000 74812000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 74f90000 750ec000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 75180000 751ce000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 75ec0000 75f89000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 74f80000 74f8a000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 76160000 761fd000   C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 74f30000 74f65000   C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 77130000 77136000   C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
ModLoad: 72dc0000 72f50000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7601.18455_none_72d576ad8665e853\gdiplus.dll
ModLoad: 722e0000 722fc000   C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 722c0000 722c7000   C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
ModLoad: 75ff0000 7607f000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 73850000 73859000   C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 743c0000 743ee000   C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 744f0000 74610000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 743a0000 743ac000   C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 6b730000 6b745000   C:\Windows\system32\Cabinet.dll
ModLoad: 74c20000 74dbd000   C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 744b0000 744d7000   C:\Windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
ModLoad: 74690000 746a2000   C:\Windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
(10c4.240): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=003ff5ac edx=770370f4 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=770905a6 esp=003ff5c8 ebp=003ff5f4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
770905a6 cc              int     3

0:000> g
ModLoad: 74c00000 74c1f000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 76230000 762fc000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
(10c4.240): Illegal instruction - code c000001d (first chance)
(10c4.240): Illegal instruction - code c000001d (!!! second chance !!!)
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for bootstrapper.exe
eax=00000001 ebx=003ff610 ecx=003ff60c edx=00000006 esi=003ff60c edi=003ff60c
eip=001cb6bd esp=003ff484 ebp=003ff488 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00010246
bootstrapper+0x3b6bd:
001cb6bd f30fe6c0        cvtdq2pd xmm0,xmm0
```

Could somebody advise what can be the problem?

Comment: Its very difficult to guess what the problem could be with just this info. Can you share a little more details about your environment. Like - does the problem occurs always.
- what changed in the system for the problem to occur.

Also please execute `!analyze -v` and share its output.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the installation files again or verifying the checksums?